# How to make a filter configurable in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I have a df:

```
  col1 col2
0  A   23
1  B   25
2  C   26
3  D   92
```

Now I need to filter this df on col1 to get the values for A and C. So I do the following:

```
filter1 = (df['col1'] == 'A') | (df['col1'] == 'C')
new_df = df[filter1]
```

This will give me the df with rows 0 and 2. However how can I make this configurable ? For example currently we are filtering on A or C maybe in the future I need to include D, or include B etc. How can I write this so that I make my filter configurable and just change the values in a list of something and the df filter gets updated?

Comment: `df[df['col1'].isin(['A', 'C'])]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
yourList=["All the values you need to be filtered"]


df[df['col1'].isin(yourList)]
```